# Select All doesn't work unless I select something

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I'm using AngularJS, working with objects

```
vm.getAllPermissions = function(category) {
    return vm.allPermissions[category];
};

vm.unselectAll = function(category, selectedPermissions) {
selectedPermissions = selectedPermissions === undefined ? []  :     selectedPermissions;
    var permissions = vm.getAllPermissions(category);
    for (var i = selectedPermissions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (permissions.indexOf(selectedPermissions[i]) > -1) {
            selectedPermissions.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
};

vm.selectAll = function(category, selectedPermissions) {
selectedPermissions = selectedPermissions === undefined ? []  : selectedPermissions;
    vm.unselectAll(category, selectedPermissions);
    var permissions = vm.getAllPermissions(category);
    for (var i = permissions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        selectedPermissions.push(permissions[i]);
    }
};
```

And permissions is an array. `vm.unselectAll` is working perfectly. `vm.selectAll` works if the user selects at least a permission, but if all the checkbox are empty, then select all will select nothing at all.

The console error is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at RolesController.vm.unselectAll (roles.controller.js:95)
    at RolesController.vm.selectAll (roles.controller.js:103)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:13628), <anonymous>:4:652)
    at b (angular.js:14610)
    at e (angular.js:24071)
    at n.$eval (angular.js:16359)
    at n.$apply (angular.js:16459)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:24076)
    at Pf (angular.js:3374)
    at HTMLButtonElement.d (angular.js:3362)
```

Edit, the html

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" ng-click="vm.cancel()"><span aria-hidden="true"><em class="fa fa-times resizable"></em></span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">{{vm.title}}</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form name='form' class='form-horizontal' role="form" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
        <fieldset ng-disabled="vm.displaying">
            <div class="form-group" ng-show="vm.editing">
                <label class='control-label col-md-2' for='id_id'>{{'ID' | translate}}</label>
                <div class='col-md-2'>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id ='id_id' ng-model="vm.data.id" disabled />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='control-label col-md-2' for='id_name'>{{'NAME' | translate}}</label>
                <div class='col-md-4'> 
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id ='id_name' ng-model="vm.data.name" required autofocus/>
                </div>               
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='control-label col-md-3' for='id_name'>{{'PERMISSIONS' | translate}} :</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <uib-tabset type="tabs" vertical="false" justified="false">       
                        <uib-tab class="nav nav-tabs" ng-repeat="category in vm.parent.getPermissionsCategories()" >
                           <uib-tab-heading>{{vm.parent.getPermissionCategoryTitle(category)}}</uib-tab-heading>
                                <table class="table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <button class="btn btn-default btn-flat btn-sm" ng-click="vm.parent.selectAll(category, vm.data.permissions)">{{'ACTION_SELECT_ALL' | translate}}</button>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <button class="btn btn-default btn-flat btn-sm" ng-click="vm.parent.unselectAll(category, vm.data.permissions)">{{'ACTION_UNSELECT_ALL' | translate}}</button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                             <!--        .parent for ng-repeat
                                    .parent.parent for ng-if -->
                                        <tr ng-if="$index%3==0" ng-repeat="permission in vm.parent.getAllPermissions(category)">
                                            <td ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2]" class="col-xs-2">
                                                <span ng-if="vm.parent.getPermission(category,$parent.$index+i)">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="vm.data.permissions" checklist-value="vm.parent.getPermission(category,$parent.$parent.$index+i)">
                                                    {{vm.parent.getPermissionTitle(category,$parent.$parent.$index+i)}}
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                        </uib-tab>            
                    </uib-tabset>            
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type='submit' ng-click="vm.submit()" ng-if="!vm.displaying" ng-disabled='form.$invalid'>{{vm.actionTitle}}</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="vm.cancel()">{{vm.closeTitle}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's the output of `console.log(selectedPermissions);`

```
[]
roles.controller.js:108 ["security:role:query"]
roles.controller.js:108 ["security:role:query", "security:role:delete"]
roles.controller.js:108 ["security:role:query", "security:role:delete", "security:role:update"]
roles.controller.js:108 ["security:role:query", "security:role:delete", "security:role:update", "security:role:create"]
roles.controller.js:108 ["security:role:query", "security:role:delete", "security:role:update", "security:role:create", "security:role:read"]
roles.controller.js:108 ["security:role:query", "security:role:delete", "security:role:update", "security:role:create", "security:role:read", "security:role:manage"]
roles.controller.js:108 ["security:role:query", "security:role:delete", "security:role:update", "security:role:create", "security:role:read", "security:role:manage", "security:user:query"]
roles.controller.js:108 ["security:role:query", "security:role:delete", "security:role:update", "security:role:create", "security:role:read", "security:role:manage", "security:user:query", "security:user:delete"]
roles.controller.js:108 ["security:role:query", "security:role:delete", "security:role:update", "security:role:create", "security:role:read", "security:role:manage", "security:user:query", "security:user:delete", "security:user:update"]
roles.controller.js:108 ["security:role:query", "security:role:delete", "security:role:update", "security:role:create", "security:role:read", "security:role:manage", "security:user:query", "security:user:delete", "security:user:update", "security:user:create"]
roles.controller.js:108 ["security:role:query", "security:role:delete", "security:role:update", "security:role:create", "security:role:read", "security:role:manage", "security:user:query", "security:user:delete", "security:user:update", "security:user:create", "security:user:read"]
```

I think it's an html issue because I debugged selectall and all the data is there, working normally, I think table cells aren't being filled

Comment: Why are you calling unselectAll in selectAll?

Comment: @Jecoms to clean it, otherwise I will have duplicate permission selected, so i empty the array and then I select all

Comment: What is the value for `permissions` and `selectedPermissions` inside `selectAll` function when you call it? Does permissions have the desired length?

Comment: It looks like selectedPermissions is undefined, based off of line numbers and counting. Try adding *selectedPermissions = selectedPermissions === undefined ? []  : selectedPermissions;* above where you make the call to vm.unselectAll

Comment: @tuckerjt07 try adding what? try adding items inside permissions array? thats what im trying to do

Comment: I gave you the line of code in italics in the comment, I'm on a phone so I can type an answer but it will take a minute to complete.

Comment: Added the line into your code in an answer below

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will avoid duplicate permission to push and with selectall functionality

```
vm.selectAll = function(category, selectedPermissions) {
    var permissions = vm.getAllPermissions(category);
    for (var i = permissions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(selectedPermissions.indexOf(permissions[i])<0) {
           selectedPermissions.push(permissions[i]);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: The issue is still there, if i select a permission, only then the button works

Answer (score 0):

Based off of line numbers and counting selectedPermissions is undefined try this.

Once you get that working there are some other things you could do to reduce complexity and lines of code.

```
vm.getAllPermissions = function(category) {
    return vm.allPermissions[category];
};

vm.unselectAll = function(category, selectedPermissions) {
    var permissions = vm.getAllPermissions(category);
    for (var i = selectedPermissions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (permissions.indexOf(selectedPermissions[i]) > -1) {
            selectedPermissions.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
};

vm.selectAll = function(category, selectedPermissions) {
    selectedPermissions = selectedPermissions === undefined ? []  : selectedPermissions; //This is the null/undefined check you're missing
    vm.unselectAll(category, selectedPermissions);
    var permissions = vm.getAllPermissions(category);
    for (var i = permissions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        selectedPermissions.push(permissions[i]);
    }
};
```

Comment: I dont see the error anymore but the issue isn't fixed

Comment: Can you console.log(selectedPermissions) after the for loop in selectAll completes and post the output? I can't see the HTML but I'm assuming you're passing in a ng-model variable into the function. When it comes in undefined the bindings may not be in place to have it update itself in the view. If so please add that variable to the console.log(selectedPermissions, vm.ThatVariable)

Answer (score -1):

This should fix it:

```
// This should be initialized elsewhere in the controller for this to work
var selectedPermissions = [];
```

Alternatively you could check for this value before making a call to the `selectAll` function:

```
//possible other actions performed
selectedPermissions = selectedPermissions || []; //This should be present before every call made to selectAll
vm.selectAll(category, selectedPermissions);

vm.selectAll = function(category, selectedPermissions) {
    selectedPermissions = []; //Since you are aiming to empty selected permissions
    var permissions = vm.getAllPermissions(category);
    for (var i = permissions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        selectedPermissions.push(permissions[i]);
    }
};
```

Unless there are permissions in `selectedPermissions` which are not present in `permissions`. In which case, mareeskannan's answer is more appropriate.

I believe you could probably keep your function as is even. The critical thing here is making sure the `selectedPermissions` is initialized to an empty array. If its initial value is not defined then it will be passed by value instead of passed by reference.

Alternatively, you can make `selectAll` return the selected permissions:

```
vm.selectAll = function(category, selectedPermissions) {
    if (selectedPermissions) {
       vm.unselectAll(category, selectedPermissions);
    } else {
        selectedPermissions = []; //Since you are aiming to empty selected permissions
    }
    var permissions = vm.getAllPermissions(category);
    for (var i = permissions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        selectedPermissions.push(permissions[i]);
    }
    return selectedPermissions;
};
```

Comment: I'm looking into your comment to answer it and your answer does not work, now the selectall doesn't work at all

Comment: I probably need to know a few more things then, one question is what selectedPermissions is, how is it set. Might need to see the rest of your code for the controller to figure this out. A jsfiddle or plunker might be even better. I think selectPermissions is not getting passed by reference possibly, in your case. Might be undefined even when the function starts.

Comment: if i declare outside the scope of the function then other stuff will be messed up, on the site, will tell u what selectPermission is when I get home, I don't know where the other developer put it now, I'll ask him when home

Comment: There must be a declaration at some point, or where the call is made, else  this will not work. Alternatively you can return this value and assign to selectedPermissions, which might be a better option. As long as its not undefined when the call is made this should be fine. You could set it to itself or empty array just before the function call, as one solution.

Comment: When passing a variable in as a parameter it does not need to have a declaration elsewhere in the function. It simply needs an undefined/null check and appropriate action taken.